# Iterate over dynamic table in selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Got a dynamic table with clickable rows. I am trying to iterate over all rows however I can only click on the first row before receiving the following error:

**StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**

Workable code below:

```
# Retrive table and rows
table_id = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ember-table-overflow")
rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
back_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"navigation__links")

# Total number of components
print(len(rows))

comp_list = []
for row in rows[1:2]:
    print(row)
    time.sleep(10)
    row.click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    kind = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "component-view-spec__body"})[0].text
    print(kind)
    LV = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "component-view-spec__body"})[1].text
    comp_data = {
        'Kind': kind,
        'LV': LV,
        }
    comp_list.append(comp_data)
    back_btn.click()
```

Code error when iterating more than one row:

```
# Total number of components
print(len(rows))

comp_list = []
for row in rows[1:3]:
    print(row)
    time.sleep(10)
    row.click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    kind = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "component-view-spec__body"})[0].text
    print(kind)
    LV = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "component-view-spec__body"})[1].text
    comp_data = {
        'Kind': kind,
        'LV': LV,
        }
    comp_list.append(comp_data)
    back_btn.click()
```

Can someone point out why it errors out on row.click() ? Is it a timeout issue?

Comment: The error makes it pretty clear.  If either of your `click` calls causes the page to be refreshed, then the DOM you have captured in the `rows` list is no longer valid.  The browser has built a new DOM.

Comment: Can you confirm the url?